# Как стилизовать селект (пункты меню наезжают друг на друга)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css3

Хочу стилизовать выпадающий список с помощью библиотеки [easydropdown.js](https://github.com/patrickkunka/easydropdown), стилизовать стрелочки

[image: открывающая] [image: закрывающая]

сделать так, чтобы раскрывающийся список не сдвигал контент и пункты не наезжали друг на друга. Набросал [фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/ehgnhodp/3/)

```html
<fieldset>
  <select tabindex="4" class="dropdown">
    <option value="" class="label" value="">Month</option>
    <option value="1">January</option>
    ...
    <option value="12">December</option>
  </select>

  <select tabindex="5" class="dropdown" data-settings='{"cutOff": 12}'>
    <option value="" class="label">Day</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    ...
    <option value="31">31</option>
  </select>

  <select tabindex="6" class="dropdown" data-settings='{"cutOff": 12}'>
    <option value="" class="label">Year</option>
    <option value="2013">2015</option>
    ...
    <option value="2010">2010</option>
  </select>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: Если честно, совсем не понимаю. Тут вы пишите `easydropdown`, а в фидле - `jquery mobile`. Предоставьте нормальный пример кода

Comment: @xaja так в фидле же подключен easydropdown в External Resources, ну и jquery соответственно - что не так?

Comment: @Вася у Вас также стоит галочка: jQuery Mobile 1.4.2

Comment: @Alexander Igorevich без галочки стилизация библиотеки вообще не работает..

Answer (score 2):

Надеюсь, что [данная песочница](http://cssdeck.com/labs/styling-select-box-with-css3) Вам поможет

**HTML**

```
<label>
    <select>
        <option selected> Select Box </option>
        <option>Short Option</option>
        <option>This Is A Longer Option</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

**CSS**

```css
body, html {background:#444; text-align:center; padding:50px 0;}

/* The CSS */
select {
    padding:3px;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #fff inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #fff inset;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #fff inset;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    color:#888;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    appearance:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}

/* Targetting Webkit browsers only. FF will show the dropdown arrow with so much padding. */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    select {padding-right:18px}
}

label {position:relative}
label:after {
    content:'<>';
    font:11px "Consolas", monospace;
    color:#aaa;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    right:8px; top:2px;
    padding:0 0 2px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
    position:absolute;
    pointer-events:none;
}
label:before {
    content:'';
    right:6px; top:0px;
    width:20px; height:20px;
    background:#f8f8f8;
    position:absolute;
    pointer-events:none;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<label>
    <select>
        <option selected> Select Box </option>
        <option>Short Option</option>
        <option>This Is A Longer Option</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

Comment: Во-первых, лучше скопировать код в ответ. Во-вторых, в IE11 что-то не то - кусок стрелки видно.

Comment: Ну пардон. Я и так с телефона

Comment: Как в оффисе буду - так и дополню

Comment: @Roman Kozin вы уже побывали в офисе?

Comment: @Вася, я дополнил еще вчера

Comment: @Qwertiy, Я использую Edge. Microsoft Edge

Comment: @Roman Kozin я если честно, не понял, что изменилось - стрелочки какими были, таки и остались - даже у меня в фидле в описании лучше получается

Comment: @Вася, а я и не говорил, что фидл буду править. Я же сказал, что дополню свое сообщение. А уже исходя с фидла, который я дал, Вы сможете сконструировать `select`'ы, которые Вам надо.

Comment: @Roman Kozin спасибо, конечно, но я не представляю как с помощью такого селекта добавить стрелочки и сделать пункты меню, к примеру, больше по разрерам